# How to check for an Empty String

Tags: java, string, error-handling

I am trying to assign a default value to variable if the variable holds an empty string. I used the following codes but they are not working out:

```
if (d.lat.trim().isEmpty())
   latt = 9.0819990;
else {
   latt = Double.valueOf(d.lat.trim()).doubleValue();
}
```

**The above code results in an error:**

```
cannot find symbol
symbol  : method isEmpty()
location: class java.lang.String
```

then I used

```
if (" ".equals(d.lat.trim()))
   latt = 9.0819990;
else {
   latt = Double.valueOf(d.lat.trim()).doubleValue();
}
```

The code above jumps the `if` section and tries to convert the empty String into double thereby throwing error about empty string.

SO, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Double.valueOf(str).doubleValue()` can be shortened to `Double.parseDouble(str)`

Comment: It could be further shortened to `latt = new Double(str)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The empty string is `""`, not `" "` (note that there is no space between the quotes).

Answer (score 3):

NPE is correct.
But may I recommend Apache `StringUtils`  .
http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isBlank(java.lang.String)

Checks if a String is whitespace, empty ("") or null.

```
 StringUtils.isBlank(null)      = true
 StringUtils.isBlank("")        = true
 StringUtils.isBlank(" ")       = true
 StringUtils.isBlank("bob")     = false
 StringUtils.isBlank("  bob  ") = false
```

Answer (score 1):

The first block looks ok to me, but you are probably compiling with Java5, which does not have the `String.isEmpty()` method yet.

Answer (score 1):

What if you use `String.length() == 0` instead of `String.isEmpty()` ?

Answer (score 1):

Apache StringUtils is a very good way to solve the problems for the validation you're implementing. Nevertheless, it seems very strange the error that you can't use the .isEmpty method, what version of the JDK are you using? Try to change the version of your JDK in the classpath with a latest version (JDK 7) or at least with the JDK 6.

Also remember that empty String is represented by "", just the quotes without any blank. It seems the way you're validating is ok. You can try with something like this.

```
if (d.lat.trim().isEmpty() || d.lat.length == 0)
   latt = 9.0819990;
else {
   latt = Double.valueOf(d.lat.trim()).doubleValue();
   // or as mentioned before: latt = Double.parseDouble(d.lat.trim());
}
```